# Can I send two-sided copies to USCIS?

Tags: usa, immigration, uscis

My tax returns are 80 pages long **EACH** when printed from TurboTax. I want to send three years. Can I print double-sided?

Answer (score 2):

## No

From [USCIS: Form Filing Tips](https://www.uscis.gov/forms/filing-guidance/form-filing-tips)

> - Send single-sided copies of your supporting documentation.